# Can't put a json on a Map on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to get the data from a json and save into a map to use the data on my app, but i cant make it work.

Here´s the json example:

```
[
    {
        "Codigo_Produto": 2025,
        "Qtde": 4,
        "Descricao": "SERVIÇO DE ALINHAR EIXOS",
        "Codigo": 3862,
        "CodOS": 3862,
        "Numero_da_OS": "3862"
    },
    {
        "Codigo_Produto": 2423,
        "Qtde": 4,
        "Descricao": "SERVIÇO DE CAMBAGEM TRAÇÃO/TRUCK",
        "Codigo": 3862,
        "CodOS": 3862,
        "Numero_da_OS": "3862"
    }
]
```

Here is how i try to access the data:

```
       Map<dynamic, dynamic> map =
        jsonDecode(response.data);
         print(map);
```

And i get this error:

```
E/flutter (15734): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I have also tried making in different ways but everytime i get this error.

What is wrong with my code? Is it because the response is coming insite a array? What is the best way to receive and make this data usable for my app?

The full code on the button that calls the api is here:

```
onPressed: () async {
                                  Response response;
                                  Dio dio = new Dio();
                                  String url =
                                      'http://192.168.15.2:8090/api/getOs';
                                  response = await dio.post(url, data: {
                                    "numeroos": _numeroOsController.text
                                  });
                                  print(response.statusCode);



                                  print(response.data);
                                  Navigator.pop(context, true);

                                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `response.data` returns list. Check first line of your json, it has list brackets like this `[`.

You should retrieve your data this way:

```
final listOfObjects = <String,dynamic>[];

for(var obj in response.data)
{
  listOfObjects.add(jsonDecode(obj));
}

return listOfObjects;
```

You need to change return type of your Future also, to list of your objects.

Comment: Where should i change? I'm not using a future, i will put the full code on the post, could you take a look?

Comment: okay i see, then after your await, put code from example i wrote and in List listOfObjects will be stored all your response data. You can then map them into widgets or use them however you like.

Comment: Doesnt work, i get the error on <String, dynamic> part: List literals require exactly one type argument or none, but 2 found.
Try adjusting the number of type arguments.dart(expected_one_list_type_arguments)

Comment: My bad, it should look like this final listOfObjects = <Map<String,dynamic>>[]; Bcs you get list of map from your response

Answer (score 0):

Using the json.decode you can extract the data directly to map

```
String responseBody = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/data.json");
var maplist = await json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

Comment: Got the error: E/flutter (15734): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/data.json

Comment: I have a doubt .. your fetching data from cloud or from local json file ? . If your fetching the data from the local json file you have to add the json in your pubspec.yaml file.